# Unit test for protocol over cin/cout - how to block on streams to wait for content?

Tags: c++, io, istream

I'm trying to write a unit test for a program which needs to communicate with another process over a protocol through cin/cout pipe. It works well when excuting and testing with keyboard or another program sending and receiving commands and responses.

In the unit test I would obviously need to replace cin/cout with other streams I can send and receive data from. (Through another thread and writing to the input stream of the protocol handler)

Unfortunately I can't find a method to get a blocking read method which waits until a stream gets more content.

The code below works fine when using cin.

```
void Handler::loop() {
  string cmd, token;
  do {
    cout << "HANDLER WAIT FOR COMMAND:" << endl;

    // Block here waiting for input or EOF
    // only blocks on cin!!
    if (!getline(*pInputStream, cmd)) cmd = "quit";

    //  create the stream object
    istringstream inStream(cmd);

    inStream >> skipws >> token;
    cout << "HANDLER RECEIVED: " << token << endl;

    if (token == "quit") break;
    // handle commands...
    else if (token == "noop") /* noop */;
    else cerr << "Unknown command: " << token << endl;
    cout << "HANDLER COMMAND PROCESSED: " << token << endl;

  } while (token != "quit");
}
```

When using

```
istringstream is;
```

instead of cin  then 'getline(*pInputStream, cmd)' does not block any more and returns with -1 immediately. I can't find any other mothed which would accomplish what I need (if have done some research for some time now).

In Java I implemented it with:

```
final BufferedReader in = 
    new BufferedReader(newnputStreamReader(inputStream));

while (running) {
  try {
    // wait until a line is ready to be read
    final String readLine = in.readLine();
...
```

This works fine with System.in or other streams. in.readline() always blocks until content is availabe. Ideal for unit testing.

So speficically how can this be accomplished in C++ or more generally how to unit test protocols over inter process pipes?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`std:::getline` returns the input stream object you gave it as argument. The stream itself will have a state which is used to determine if it should be evaluated as `true` or `false` in a boolean context. I made your loop able to accept a generic `std::istream` so it can be tested both with `std::cin` and other istreams. First run usues `std::cin` and second run usues a `std::istringstream` to show that it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

void loop(std::istream& is) {
    std::cout << "-----------------------------\n";
    std::string cmd, token;
    do {
        std::cout << "HANDLER WAIT FOR COMMAND:\n";

        // Block here waiting for input or EOF
        // only blocks on cin!!
        if(!getline(is, cmd)) cmd = "quit";

        //  create the stream object
        std::istringstream inStream(cmd);

        inStream >> std::skipws >> token;
        std::cout << "HANDLER RECEIVED: " << token << "\n";

        if(token == "quit") break;
        // handle commands...
        else if(token == "noop") /* noop */
            ;
        else
            std::cerr << "Unknown command: " << token << "\n";
        std::cout << "HANDLER COMMAND PROCESSED: " << token << "\n";

    } while(token != "quit");
}

int main() {
    loop(std::cin);
    std::istringstream ss("unknown\nnoop\nquit\nafter quit\n");
    loop(ss);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted. But your ss istringstream is only a single stream - the loop will exit at the end even without quit as getline thinks the stream is EOF. What I'm aiming at is having the Handler::loop run in a seperate thread. Then send a command from a unit test - wait for a result, send next command, etc.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure I get exactly what you'd like to do. Is the Handler::loop` supposed to emulate the program? if so, doesn't it stop executing when `std::cin` is closed? If so, wouldn't starting a new thread and supplying it with a new `std::istream` whenever the old stream gets depleted?

Comment: The code
     if(!getline(is, cmd)) ...
works as expected with std::cin because it blocks as long as there is no input from the keyboard or process pipe.
But in a unit test there will be no keyboard or process pipe so I need getline() to block on an empty stream (empty does not mean closed).
In Java this is easy as Java's readLine distinguishes between empty (blocking) and closed. readLine() would wait until there is new content in the stream. 
getline() in C++ on the other hand does not block when a stream is empty (only when the stream is cin.)

Comment: Is cin special and can I get getline() block on any other kind of stream?

Comment: As long as the `std::istream` is open and not at `eof` it should block. A `stringstream` will however be depleated and reach `eof` very fast. In linux, you could create a filesystem pipe (`mknod cmd_pipe p`) and open that for reading and use as `std::istream`. As long as it's open, the `getline` function will block and then you can send commands at any speed you want.